# Colors of reputation points graph and tag advances not matching

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, reputation-history

I observed today that the color of the line showing reputation as a function of time in the user's activity page suddenly differs from the color of the tag advancement in the field below that.

[image]

The color of the reputation graph is `#5fba7d`, while that of the tag score is `#5bd287`.

Could that be changed such that both are the same (please)?

Comment: This is of the utmost importance. This must be fixed immediately!

Comment: @TinyGiant Lol, I'm sure there are more important and urgent things to do on the side, but it's kind of strange and I would like to bring it to some responsible's attention.

Comment: No argument here, as I said, this is of the utmost importance.

Comment: The color of the accepted answer square is also `#5fba7d`, so that seems to be the correct color. It's the tag advancement color that is wrong.

Comment: Also, if you track a privilege instead of a tag, the color is then `linear-gradient(to right, #D0F4DD 0, #A7F0C1 100%)`. That color is even more off.

Comment: I liked the dark one. The light one is too "shiny".

Comment: I would much prefer it if the Stack Exchange staff spent their time doing something that actually makes a difference.  Can I vote to close this as "no action required" please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph color has been updated to better match with the progress bars. This is now live in production.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: See? What did I say? Utmost importance.

Comment: shouldn;t this question be marked as [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: Now the colours don't match the 'recently gained reputation' colour box (in your picture, the +381). :(

Comment: Why do there have to be so many different colors of green on a single page? "Less is more", and all that.

Comment: This did not fix the problem. This just made another element the wrong color. `#5fba7d` is the color that is used for green everywhere else on the site, so it's the progress bar color that needed to be changed, not the graph.