# The many shades of green

Tags: feature-request, design

This question is a follow up to [Colors of reputation points graph and tag advances not matching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351412/colors-of-reputation-points-graph-and-tag-advances-not-matching/351417).

The above question addressed the fact that the green color used in the reputation graph and tag advances, did not match. The graph used `#5fba7d` while the tag advances progress bars used `linear-gradient(to right, #5ED286 0, #23D59B 100%)`.

> [image: original]

Hynes "fixed" this problem by changing the graph color to better match the tag advances color:

> [image: new]

This "fix", however, created a bigger design issue, rather than fix the problem. `#5fba7d` is the green color used for many other elements on the site. The color of the graph was correct, and it was a progress bars that should have been changed.

---

Examples of other elements on the site that use the `#5fba7d` green color:

Accept check:

> [image: accept check]

Accepted answer reputation:

> [image: accepted answer reputation]

Newly earned reputation points in the Activity tab:

> [image: new rep]

Reputation graph in the Activity tab summary. The actual color here is a lighter shade of that green, and turns to `#5fba7d` on hover.

> [image: rep graph]

---

When looking around for other elements, I did find two other elements with a different green color, but `#5fba7d` still seems to be the default green color for Stack Overflow.

The privileged progress bar uses a gradient of much lighter shades of green. These shades of green do not seem to be used anywhere else on the site, and the color also does not go with the other site colors.

> [image: progress]

The reputation graph on the reputation tab uses a darker shade of green, which also does not seem to be used anywhere else on the site:

> [image: reputation]

---

All I can say is that this lack of consistency is making me feel a little...green! Can the graph color "fix" be reverted and can all the elements be changed to use the same shade of green?

Comment: I agree, it should at least all be the same shade of green. I prefer the old vs the new green (or at least something a little less saturated and bright), but that's just a matter of personal preference I guess.

Comment: [It's not easy...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bein%27_Green)

Comment: Green is the new black

Comment: If you guys don't stop nitpicking, the SO devs will probably be turning many shades of red ;-)

Comment: [webdesign used to be much simpler](http://www.dpgraph.com/)

Comment: Just wondering, if every color is hardcoded or they use a css-preprocessor.

Comment: @Ihazkode, wow, I wouldn't be afraid to visualize more than 8th dimension after that.

Comment: The profile design and colours are the easiest part of the website to maintain: __just don't touch them__. Please :( Every week I start to twitch a bit, and spend minutes figuring out what's wrong. When I find it, I keep twitching.

Comment: While 256 would be preferred, I think we should aim to have a minimum of 128 shades of green throughout the site.

Comment: @kojow7 It's simple, use a function to generate a random shade of green for each element on the page.

Comment: Who cares that they didn’t match to begin with? It looked fine.

Comment: Really, who cares. I'm sure they have better things to spend their time on.

Comment: The problem is that they _used to match_ with the nice old rep green. Then the progress bar was changed to a horrid bright green, then the graph was changed to match it. The least amount of work would've been not touching the colours in the first place. (cc @Lundin)

Comment: Again, utmost importance. On with the fixing!