# Progress bar color too bright?

Tags: discussion, design

Am I the only one that thinks the color on the progress bar in the user profile is too bright? It makes me feel dizzy. At the moment the color used is this gradient:

```
linear-gradient(to right, #5ED286 0, #23D59B 100%)
```

Comment: [You are not the only one feeling green](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351530/the-many-shades-of-green)